Errors were encountered while processing: linux-image-6.2.0-37-generic linux-image-6.5.0-35-generic
Setting up linux-image-6.2.0-37-generic (6.2.0-37.38~22.04.1) ...
Setting up linux-image-6.5.0-35-generic (6.5.0-35.35~22.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for linux-image-6.2.0-37-generic (6.2.0-37.38~22.04.1) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 6.2.0-37-generic
   ...done.
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-6.2.0-37-generic
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 10: /etc/default/grub: quiet splash: not found
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-6.2.0-37-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-6.2.0-37-generic package post-installation script subproc
ess returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for linux-image-6.5.0-35-generic (6.5.0-35.35~22.04.1) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 6.5.0-35-generic
   ...done.
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-35-generic
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 10: /etc/default/grub: quiet splash: not found
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-6.5.0-35-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-6.5.0-35-generic package post-installation script subproc
ess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-6.2.0-37-generic
 linux-image-6.5.0-35-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

I am new to ubuntu and while updating using sudo apt upgrade i get these errors. Please help. I cant even install any other software?

Thank gods. It finally worked needed to run updtae-grub after restoring the content of the file, Thank you so much.
